# IBM MobileFirst platform adapter deployment failed. Missing JMS spec classes in the classpath

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, websphere-liberty, mobilefirst-adapters, mobilefirst-server

I created a new JMS adapter in my IBM MobileFirst platform project following the instructions at the [IBM Documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSHSCD_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.dev.doc/devref/t_connecting_jms_adapters_to_websphere_mq.html)

I copied the Jars in the **server/lib** folder, added them to the build path and made changes to the adapter implementation.

But when I try to deploy the adapter I get the following error.

> Adapter deployment failed: Missing JMS spec classes in the classpath. Make sure that your application server supports JMS and that the feature is enabled in server configuration

I checked the server.xml and the jars are added to the classpath. Not sure what is causing the issue.

Comment: Do you not think you should mention about the application server as well?Have you verified if JMS feature is enabled? If it is Liberty add its, feature supported tags to the question.

Comment: Embedded Liberty MobileFirst Studio 7.1.0.00

Comment: @VivinK  This is both on Embeded Liberty and Liberty Core Servers,  We are not using Liberties built in JMS since neither environments support it.  But according to IBM Docs, we would be able to import into the lib directory the supporting MQ client lib files.  We have done that, but it has not make a difference.

Comment: Can you verify if the server.xml has enabled the feature tag for jms?

Comment: Seems for core/embedded you cannot add the jms feature tag.  From IBM site:WebSphere Application Server Liberty Core does not include Java Message Service (JMS) or Web Services, making Liberty Core edition lightweight and focused on the capabilities that are needed to deliver Web Profile applications.